# Use Angular to set a class based on number of repeated items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a table populated with Angular.js data:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Username</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="t in tabledata">
        <td>00{{t.id}}</td>
        <td>{{t.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{t.lastName}}</td>
        <td><a href="">{{t.userName}}</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

What I would *like* to do is add another class to the `table` tag if the number of rows of data > 10.

Is this possible, and how would I go about it? I know how to do this with a "flat" table in jQuery, but I'm new to the dynamic repeaters of Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-class`

```
<table ng-class="{'newClassName' : tabledata.length > 10 }">
```

Comment: thanks.  Is this ok even if there already is a class, as in `<table class="table" ng-class="{'table-striped': (tabledata.length > 10)}">`?  Seems to work, but is it correct?

Comment: @Steve -- Yep, no problem with that